# Clean up test cases

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework

How do companies clean up test cases? If I have 5000 tests in my library and 1000 of them are deprecated because we have cleaned up the code associated originally, how do we ensure that the tests are removed?

Comment: How test cases are stored? Which tool?

Comment: Are the tests actually _marked_ as deprecated, or are you looking for a way to identify tests to deprecate/remove based on code changes? Based on your comment on Kate's answer it sounds like you're actually wanting a way to link test cases to code/functionality. You might try editing your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends**

Some of the factors that can affect how aggressively automated test cases are deprecated include:

- **Mission-critical** - regression tests that cover essential functionality of an application are much less likely to be retired than regression tests covering optional functions.
- **Frequently used** - regression tests of frequently used features are less likely to be retired than regression tests of rarely used features.
- **Fragile** - regression tests that cover areas of the application known to be prone to breakage are less likely to be retired than tests of areas known to be stable.
- **Retired/deprecated functionality** - regression tests that cover deprecated or retired functionality get removed as soon as is feasible.
- **Regulated** - tests used to verify or validate regulated functionality will not be retired unless the regulation involved changes.

Ultimately, it depends on the business and the team: if the tests continue to pass and don't overload available resources, many organizations are likely to have no issues with retaining them. Tests that fail because functionality has changed will be either rewritten or replaced so that they cover current functionality.

What matters is that the method you are using works for you and your team.

Comment: How do you like test cases to functions/methods?

Answer (score 1):

> How do companies clean up test cases?

Test cases need to be maintained. Part of that process involves cleaning out obsolete cases.

Doing this is simply a project that needs to be assigned to someone periodically. Sometimes cleanup is a task within another project.